# SQLite3 cant fetch columns

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I wrote my code as simple as possible to make a simple login, because its my first time working with SQLite3 databases.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$db  = new SQLite3("FirstDatabase.db");

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM data WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
    $query->execute();

    $count = $query->fetchColumn();

    if($count = 1){
        echo "Welcome $username!";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong credentials";
    }
}

?>
```

I'm really confused why this is not working.. I updated all the extensions etc.
I know this is vulnerable to pretty much every type of attack, but I'm just trying to figure out the SQLite3 database connection.

Thanks! :)

This is the Error I get btw:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::fetchColumn() in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP-Login\index.php:41 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP-Login\index.php on line 41

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection which could be devastating to your database and your system and your health. First and foremost you should change the select to a parametrized query.

There are very good examples [in the doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindparam.php) for using a parametrized query and binding the values, not to mention a ton of resource on this site.

The error is telling you that that there is not method `fetchColumn()` for a `SQLite3Stmt` object. The [PHP: SQLite3Stmt doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3stmt.php) confirms that. It is a method on the PDO database extension.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I do not care about security at the moment, since its only a project for the localhost (and will always be).

Comment: That's fine IMO it's a good _habit_ to build. Regardless, there is still no `fetchColum()` method, and the doc will help you find the correct method.